# How to label observations based on latent class analysis

Tags: r, modeling, latent-variable

I perform a latent class analysis to a dataset of binary variables with

```
library("BayesLCA")
data("Alzheimer")
alz <- data.blca(Alzheimer)
sj3.em <- blca.em(alz, 3)
```

**Now I want to label my observations of `Alzheimer` given the likelihood of each belonging to one particular group.**

I extract the estimate of class membership for each unique datapoint

```
class_memb <- sj3.em$Z
```

and label each unique datapoint according to the highest probability

```
labels_df <- apply(class_memb, 1, function(x) sample(names(x), 1, prob=x))
```

I collapse each row of my original dataset `Alzheimer` into a string of `1` and `0`

```
row_sequence <- apply(compl_cases_all, 1, 
                      function(x) as.factor(paste0(x, collapse='')))
```

and finally I replace the sequence of each observation with my max probability

```
grouping <- labels_df[row_sequence]
```

And yet the `classprob` and my labelling don't match. And then when I test it on a larger dataset the gap between class probabilities and proportion of labels is even wider. Am I doing something wrong?

```
sj3.em$classprob
# [1] 0.50162847 0.47880396 0.01956757
prop.table(table(grouping))
# grouping
#    Group 1    Group 2    Group 3 
#  0.54166667 0.43750000 0.02083333
```

**NOTE:** Question crossposted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29122668/1707938). Didn't receive much attention there and probably CrossValidated is more appropriate.